# A PostgreSQL timestamp field not formated in the same way when updated with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, date, timestamp

I have a *timestamp with timezone* field in PostgreSQL. 
When I update this field, I use something like this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Although the SQL works fine, the date saved seem a little bit different to a classic *timestamp with timezone* date.

```
Example:

Default value set to "now()":
date 2009-04-06 14:39:53.662522+02

Update with a date set in php:
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
date 2009-04-06 14:39:53+02
```

The numbers removed on update are probably milliseconds but I'm not sure. 
I would like to know if there is a means to obtain with PHP the same format of date?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one second resolution of timestamp you have to design your database accordingly, as by default resolution is better than a second.

Use for example the following column definition:

```
last_access_time timestamp with time zone not null
    default date_trunc('second',now())
    constraint last_access_time_full_second check (
        date_trunc('second',last_access_time)=last_access_time
    )
```

Comment: Fortunatelly the column definition could be much simpler (at least the part for the default value): last_access_time timestamp(0) with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the microtime() PHP function](https://www.php.net/microtime) to get the microseconds.